# Android Photos App Clear Data

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, stock-android, photos, google-plus-photos

I've cleared Data on the Photos app and photos are no longer showing. Any Ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Have you signed in to Google+?

Comment: I don't sync my photos to Google+

Comment: Okay then just uninstall the app or the updates and install it again...

Comment: didn't work.. all the files are there, i can see them through file explorer.. dunno what's wrong